# Adobe/mac users: what are the LS1.dmg files(can i delete them)?

Tags: macos, adobe, dmg

I'm using Disk Inventory X to help open up some space on my hard drive. I found some disk images in my users folder, each taking up more than a whole gb of space:

the files : https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfGtw.png

They seem to be installation packages for Adobe Creative Suite applications. I have CS5 already installed (as of a couple years now, just noticed these files, they may or may not have been there the whole time). The are for versions I have already installed. Here's one of them mounted:

dmg mounted contents : https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2EcJ.png

An extensive google search was no help, but the jargon file names seem to be familiar as they generate a lot of google results but again with no help as to whether or not they're spare trash or important.

I know disk images can be deleted after installation but I just want to make sure these aren't particularly important. What can I do to be sure it is safe to delete these without messing anything up? Why are they so huge? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe these are update files from Adobe which can be deleted, but to be safe: Put the files on an external disk as backup, delete it from your computer, run you're Adobe programs as you would do normally. If after a week or so you don't have any problems you could probably delete the file from the backup as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the full install images for both CS4 and CS5 applications. Presumably you'd downloaded them at some point to install.  They can be deleted, if you have copies of the media otherwise.

If you purchased through Adobe.com, you can download those images again at any time.